# Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was trying to save object of Consumer.java . But while doing it, getting below exception:

Stack trace is as below:

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.citruspay.common.domain.consumer.ConsumerDetail. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:366)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:178)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:444)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:249)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.merge(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.merge(Unknown Source)
```

Code snippet is:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ConsumerDAOImpl implements ConsumerDAO {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ConsumerDAOImpl.class);

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   public Consumer saveOrUpdate(Consumer consumer) {
      return em.merge(consumer);
   }
}
```

I am getting exception when calling method em.merge(consumer).

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "CON_CONSUMER")
public class Consumer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8211543793922969543L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;    

@Embedded   
private WalletPreference walletPreference;
@NotNull
@OneToOne   
private ConsumerDetail consumerDetail;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Version
private Date lastModified;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ConsumerStatus consumerFlag;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
private CPUser cpUser;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="consumer" ,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause="deleted <> '1'")
private List<ConsumerCustomParameter> customParameter;

public Consumer() {
}

public Consumer(String firstName, String lastName, Address contactAddress, List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber) {
    super();    
    this.created = new Date();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public WalletPreference getWalletPreference() {
    return walletPreference;
}

public void setWalletPreference(WalletPreference walletPreference) {
    this.walletPreference = walletPreference;
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}

public ConsumerDetail getConsumerDetail() {
    return consumerDetail;
}

public void setConsumerDetail(ConsumerDetail consumerDetail) {
    this.consumerDetail = consumerDetail;
}

public ConsumerStatus getConsumerFlag() {
    return consumerFlag;
}

public void setConsumerFlag(ConsumerStatus consumerFlag) {
    this.consumerFlag = consumerFlag;
}

public CPUser getCPUser(){
     return cpUser;
}

public void setCPUser(CPUser cpUser) {
    this.cpUser = cpUser;
}

public List<ConsumerCustomParameter> getCustomParameter() {
    return customParameter;
}

public void setCustomParameter(List<ConsumerCustomParameter> customParameter) {
    this.customParameter = customParameter;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Consumer [id=" + id + ", created=" + created
            + ", lastModified=" + lastModified + ", consumerFlag="
            + consumerFlag + ", customParameter=" + customParameter + "]";
}
```

Code for saving Consumer POJO:

```
 public class ConsumerProfileServiceImpl implements ConsumerProfileService        {

    @Autowired
    private ConsumerDAO consumerDAO;

    @Transactional
    public Consumer createConsumer(CPUser cpUser, DefaultPerson person) {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        ConsumerDetail consumerDetail = //setting consumer details

        consumer.setCreated(new Date());
        consumer.setConsumerFlag(ConsumerStatus.ENABLED);

        consumer.setCPUser(); // set it to some cpuser object

        ConsumerDetail savedConsumerDetails = consumerDetailDAO
            .saveOrUpdate(consumerDetail);
        consumer.setConsumerDetail(savedConsumerDetails);

        consumer = consumerDAO.saveOrUpdate(consumer);
    }
}
```

I am using Hibernate version 4.3.11.Final, Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Can you also post your pojos? `Consumer`, `ConsumerDetail` etc? And a small example replicating the problem? e.g. creating a new `Consumer` setting some data to it and trying to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying

a) In Consumer class

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   
private ConsumerDetail consumerDetail;
```

b) In ConsumerProfileServiceImpl class `createCustomer` method do not save the `consumerDetail` object, let saving the `consumer` handle it.

```
 //ConsumerDetail savedConsumerDetails = consumerDetailDAO
 //       .saveOrUpdate(consumerDetail);
 consumer.setConsumerDetail(consumerDetail );

 consumer = consumerDAO.saveOrUpdate(consumer);
```

Comment: It Worked. Thanks @elefasGR! But now getting another exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`. Shall I add it here or ask another question?

Comment: Actually I want to persist data, then use its id in other select query. How can We do it? I mean if I want to persist Consumer object and then want to use its Id in next method, can we do that?If yes, then how?

Comment: For your first comment, isn't it the same error as the above you mentioned that my solution works? Only instead of `Integer` you get `Long`. That's probably because in your `ConsumerDetails` object the id is of type `Integer` while on the `Consumer` object it's id is of type `Long`. Can't you troubleshoot it the same way? For the second comment, the answer is yes we can. But show us some of your code what are you trying to do in order to help you